# The Torero (Bullfighter)

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> I have dealt with the bull many times
>   The first was the first of the titans
>   And the second was the second of the sword.
>   The third was the first of the fallen
>   And the fourth was the second of that set.
>   The latest was the first of two
>   though I am not involved in the second.

Who am I?

Comment: oh my goodness, there's something that *almost* works with this, but not quite.

Comment: unless I've got the answer right but I'm thinking of the wrong bull...

Comment: It never hurts to guess.

Comment: Nah, I can only make most of the clues match, and even then you have to ignore the ordinals and the bull thing

Comment: @Gamow No! In fact, that takes it in an *entirely different direction* than I was going.

Comment: Why is this so difficult, when it feels like it should be so easy??

Comment: @Khale_Kitha I don't know, but I went in almost certainly the wrong direction for just long enough that I can't think of another way to think about this, haha

Comment: OH WAIT A SECOND

Comment: Something, random, just made me think this might be involved with an actor and a series of movies...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could be

> Ron Perlman

because

> The first of the Titans could be *[Cronos](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104029/?ref_=nm_flmg_dr_13)*
>  The second of the sword could be *[Blade II](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0187738/?ref_=nm_flmg_dr_10)*
>  The first and second of the fallen could be *[Hellboy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0167190/?ref_=nm_flmg_dr_9)* and *[Hellboy II](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0411477/?ref_=nm_flmg_dr_7)*
>  The latest that's the first of two could be *[Pacific Rim](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1663662/?ref_=nm_flmg_dr_6)*, since you are only rumored to be in the second

because the bull is

> [Guillermo del Toro](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0868219/), who wrote or directed each of the above

Comment: I see what happened here.  You got so excited that you sent the idea to me, mentally, of it being an actor.  Thanks.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha Funny story, my original idea was a completely different actor/director combo. I wish I could offer a reward to the first person to guess which.

Comment: Any idea what the sword referred to? - Oh, I just saw that you said you didn't.  Nm

Comment: You are correct.  If you look at the frequent collaborators section of "the Bull" on Wikipedia, you will see "the sword" <-- bit of artistic license on this one.

Comment: @APrough yep, just updated

Comment: @question_asker.  I actually did not hear that rumor about PR2.  I just assumed that based on what happened in the first excluded him.

Comment: @APrough [the website most used for that information] claims there is a rumor, but lord only knows where that info comes from

Comment: @APrough Now I'm tempted to try to form a chain based on a different mutual collaborator